# Way to correct positioning of 2 side by side images with CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, position

So I'm trying to figure out a simple way to reorganize the side-by-side images I have on a particular page on my site. Here is a link: http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/album-tile-recommendations-discography-overviews/

I know that floating the images to the left can get them to appear side by side, but as it currently stands, they're uneven and not responding the way I had hoped. What's a way that I can go about getting these images in line with one another?

And to add another question to boot - how can I then center them within the page, itself?

Here is the html I have at the moment:

```
<h><a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/albumtile1/"><font size="5"><b>David Bowie</h></a></b></font>

<a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/albumtile1/"><img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-300x300.jpg" alt="David Bowie Album Tile" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-102" style="float:left;" /></a></img>

<h><a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/brian-eno-album-tile-recommendations/"><font size="5"><b>Brian Eno</h></a></b>

<a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1.jpg"><img class="hasBorder" src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-300x300.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-488" style="float:left;" /></a></img>
```

Hopefully there's a quick and easy solution for this - unfortunately, I haven't found it yet. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thegrassrootsgarage.com%2Falbum-tile-recommendations-discography-overviews%2F

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `div` that contains the title and the image and apply to it the  `float: left` (remember removing it from both `img`)

The code should be:

```
<div style="float: left;">
    <p>
        <h>
            <a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/albumtile1/">
                <font size="5">
                    <b>David Bowie</b>
                </font>
            </a>
        </h>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/albumtile1/">
            <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-300x300.jpg" alt="David Bowie Album Tile" width="300" height="300" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-102" srcset="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-300x300.jpg 300w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-150x150.jpg 150w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-768x768.jpg 768w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile-956x956.jpg 956w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/David-Bowie-Album-Tile.jpg 1500w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
    <p>
        <h>
            <a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/uncategorized/brian-eno-album-tile-recommendations/">
                <font size="5">
                    <b>Brian Eno</b>
                </font>
            </a>
        </h>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a href="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1.jpg">
            <img class="hasBorder" src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-300x300.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="300" srcset="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-300x300.jpg 300w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-150x150.jpg 150w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-768x768.jpg 768w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-1024x1024.jpg 1024w, http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/Brian-Eno-Album-Tile-Cropped-1-956x956.jpg 956w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
        </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

*Extra tip: Consider using classes instead of inline styling.*

Comment: I had to mess around with the height and font-size/line-size properties of the <p> and <h> values of my CSS, but once that was set, it worked beautifully! Thank you so much, you're a hero. Have a wonderful day! I guess my only question now is: how can I center those <div> components? <center> doesn't appear to do the trick.

Comment: For center those <div> I personally change several things: change the `float: left;` for `display: inline-block; width: 320px;`. Then add a parent <div> with `style="text-align: center;"`

Comment: Have you consider using bootstrap? It could save you hours of styling.